# Write the recursive function missing_digits that takes a number n that is sorted in increasing order

Tags: python, recursion

Write the recursive function missing_digits that takes a number n that is sorted in increasing order (for example, 12289 is valid but 15362 and 98764 are not). It returns the number of missing digits in n. A missing digit is a number between the first and last digit of n of a that is not in n. Use recursion - the tests will fail if you use while or for loops.

```py
>>> missing_digits(1248) # 3, 5, 6, 7
4
>>> missing_digits(1122) # No missing numbers
0
>>> missing_digits(123456) # No missing numbers
0
>>> missing_digits(3558) # 4, 6, 7
3
>>> missing_digits(35578) # 4, 6
```

my code:

```py
def miss_digits2(n):
    def iter(n):
        if n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 == 1 or 0:
            return iter(n // 10)
        if n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 > 1:
             return iter(n // 10) + n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 - 1
        return iter(n)
```

can some one help me find what's wrong with my code, it returns None

Comment: Probably not the only issue, but there is already a builtin function named `iter` in python, so it is very strongly recommended to avoid using that name to name your own functions.

Comment: You're never calling the nested `iter` function from within `miss_digits2`

Comment: Why use the inner function when it just takes the same argument as the outer one? Just make `miss_digits` recursive directly

Comment: if n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 == 1 or 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison        orz

Comment: Your recursive function has no base case. It always calls itself again, ... so there is no end to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your function:

- You've defined a nested function, `iter`, which you don't use. We'll get rid of it completely and stick to a single `miss_digits` function. (`iter` is also the name of a python builtin, and you shouldn't redefine it).
- You've got no base case, which makes your code recurse infinitely.
- `if n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 == 1 or 0` does not do what you expect, and evaluates to `(n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 == 1) or (0)`, making it equivalent to `n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 == 1` as `0` is falsy in python.

After correcting these points, we end up with the following code:

```py
def miss_digits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return 0
    if n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 <= 1:
        return miss_digits(n // 10)
    else:
        return miss_digits(n // 10) + n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10 - 1
```

We can finally make the code a bit more readable by removing most of the control flow:

```py
def miss_digits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return 0
    digit_delta = n % 10 - (n // 10) % 10
    return miss_digits(n // 10) + max(digit_delta - 1, 0)
```